# Trying to assign to an @EnvironmentObject from a child view to a parent fails as EnvironmentObject is read-only

Tags: swift, mapkit, swiftui, combine, uiviewrepresentable

I have a map based app so I want to have an app-wide property for the current position of the map.

I'm initializing it in SceneDelegate

```
    let currentPosition = CurrentPosition()
    let mainView = MainView(appState: AppState(), selectedWeatherStation: nil).environmentObject(currentPosition)
```

I have it declared in `MainView` as an `@EnvironmentObject`

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var appState: AppState
    @State var selectedWeatherStation: WeatherStation? = nil

    @EnvironmentObject var currentPosition: CurrentPosition
```

and I inject it into my `UIViewRepresentable` child

```
 MapView(weatherStations: $appState.appData.weatherStations,
                    selectedWeatherStation: $selectedWeatherStation).environmentObject(currentPosition)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
```

in `MapView`

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var weatherStations: [WeatherStation]
    @Binding var selectedWeatherStation: WeatherStation?

    @EnvironmentObject var currentPosition: CurrentPosition
```

i have a final subclass

```
final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        @EnvironmentObject var currentPosition: CurrentPosition
```

which acts as my mapview delegate, where I want to update the `currentPosition`

```
  func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
            currentPosition = CurrentPosition(northEast: mapView.northEastCoordinate, southWest: mapView.southWestCoordinate)
        }
```

But this assignament
`currentPosition = CurrentPosition(northEast: mapView.northEastCoordinate, southWest: mapView.southWestCoordinate)`
will throw an error
`Cannot assign to property: 'currentPosition' is a get-only property`
and I really have no idead what I'm doing wrong.

The purpose is to update the position each time the user moves the map so I can perform a request to my API with the current coordinates.

CurrentPosition is declared as follows

```
class CurrentPosition: ObservableObject {
    @Published var northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    @Published var southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    init(northEast: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(), southWest: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D()) {
        self.northEast = northEast
        self.southWest = southWest
    }
}
```

Comment: You just change the properties of the class, rather than trying to make another class. Like so: `currentPosition.northEast = mapView.northEastCoordinate`.

Comment: @George_E that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full answer *(extended from comment)*

You just change the properties of the class, rather than trying to make another class. Like so:

```
func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    currentPosition.northEast = mapView.northEastCoordinate
    currentPosition.southWest = mapView.southWestCoordinate
}
```

The error:

> Cannot assign to property: 'currentPosition' is a get-only property

is saying that you cannot assign a value *directly* to `currentPosition`, because it is an `@ObservedObject`/`@EnvironmentObject`. It is only a gettable property.

Comment: how do u make an @environmentObject not a get-only property?

Comment: @ngb It doesn't really make sense to do that. `@EnvironmentObject` detects changes for an _instance_ of a class, which is why my solution changes a property of the class instead.